# Expecting member declaration when I use if in Android Studio

Tags: android, kotlin

I've started learning Android.
I can't use `if` in Kotlin because I saw this error
Expecting member declaration
can you help me ??

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
    }

    var fixedIncome : Int = 50
    var tips : Int = 20
    var income : Int = fixedIncome + tips

    if(tips == 0){
        Log.d("tag", "You have not recieved any tips today")
    } else {
        Log.d("tag", "You have recieved some tips today")
    }
}
```

Comment: You need to put if/else condition in `onCreate` block. Move `var` to top.

Answer (score 2):

you can't write:

```
if(tips == 0){
    Log.d("tag", "You have not recieved any tips today")
}else{
    Log.d("tag", "You have recieved some tips today")
}
```

outside the scope of a method. You're outside the `onCreate` method, you're essentially writing this in the class of `MainActivity`, so change this to:

```
var fixedIncome : Int = 50
var tips : Int = 20
var income : Int = fixedIncome + tips

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    if(tips == 0){
    Log.d("tag", "You have not recieved any tips today")
    }else{
    Log.d("tag", "You have recieved some tips today")
    }
}
```

OR, initialize and use everything in `onCreate`:

```
override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    var fixedIncome : Int = 50
    var tips : Int = 20
    var income : Int = fixedIncome + tips

    if(tips == 0){
    Log.d("tag", "You have not recieved any tips today")
    }else{
    Log.d("tag", "You have recieved some tips today")
  }

 }
```

---

As a side note:

because you're doing `var tips : Int = 20` and never changing `tips`, you might consider using `val tips : Int = 20` to indicate that it is a value, not a variable.